# Using integrals over a plane of $10^{22}$ points

Tags: calculus, integration

Ok here goes, 
I have a function that gives the magnetic field at any place on a plane by its $(x,y)$- coordinates. This magnetic field is in no way constant over this plane. What I need to do is multiply the magnetic dipole moment (not important for this question but just a property of each point) by the magnetic field at that point and I need to do this for approximately $10^{22}$ different points. These points are evenly spaced and all have the same dipole moment. Can I use integral calculus to do this?

Not sure if it's important but the surface is circular (however if for any reason it's simpler, please feel free to consider the surface a square.)

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: What is the end goal of the question you are doing, is it to calculate magnetic flux, or something?

Comment: Suppose you should say what you want to do with these $10^{22}$ products afterwards? If you want to take some average it starts looking like an integral

Comment: You could do a path intergral over those points but the end goal of the question helps really.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU In reality the "magnetic field fuction" is the derivative of it. I did not say that for simplicity. But the goal of this is to be able to calculate the force that a piece of iron should feel towards the source of this field by multiplying the magnetic moment of each atom by the change in magnetic field at that point.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh i would need to some up the products

Comment: If the magnetic field $H$ and the magnetic dipole moment $M$  are reasonably smooth functions of $(x,y)$ and you happen to know the 'density' of points $\rho(x,y)$ w.r.t. $x,y$ then you seems to be calculating $\int \int H\cdot M \rho(x,y) dx\, dy$ which may calculated numerically fairly efficiently without summing over too many points.